# ¿Como puedo mejorar este script para que no me de errores de dependencia al eliminar?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo el siguiente codigo, pero al intentar eliminar un usuario me dice que hay error, "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" al ejecutar esto especificamente "***delete from usuarios where pil_usu='CHORICILLO'**;*"     , cómo prodría corregirlo?

Dejo en el enlace el codigo de la bd, muchas gracias.

https://ideone.com/BQfFFp

```
    create table estados(
    id_est integer primary key,
    nom_est text(20)
    );

    create table usuarios(
    id_usu integer primary key autoincrement,
    pil_usu text(20),
    nom_usu text(20),
    pat_usu text(20),
    mat_usu text(20),
    dir_usu text(40),
    rut_usu text(9),
    pas_usu text(20),
    id_est integer,
    foreign key (id_est) references estados (id_est)
    );

    create table productos(
    id_pro integer primary key,
    nom_pro text(40),
    pre_pro integer,
    id_usu integer,
    id_est integer,
    foreign key (id_usu) references usuarios (id_usu),
    foreign key (id_est) references estados (id_est)
    );

    insert into estados values (1,'HABILITADO');
    insert into estados values (2,'DESHABILITADO');

    insert into usuarios (pil_usu, nom_usu, pat_usu, mat_usu, dir_usu, rut_usu, pas_usu, id_est) values ('ADMIN', 'CASTIEL', 'CARRASCO', 'MOLINA', 'NEW YORK 321', '456987123', '123456', 1);
    insert into usuarios (pil_usu, nom_usu, pat_usu, mat_usu, dir_usu, rut_usu, pas_usu, id_est) values ('CHORICILLO', 'SAMUEL', 'MATA', 'PEPE', 'LIBERTADOR 20', '123456789', 'CHORICILLO13', 1);
    insert into usuarios (pil_usu, nom_usu, pat_usu, mat_usu, dir_usu, rut_usu, pas_usu, id_est) values ('HOLA', 'DEAN' ,'CACERES', 'MEDINA', 'MOLINILLOS 354', '789456123', '123123', 1);

    insert into productos (id_pro, nom_pro, pre_pro, id_usu, id_est) values (1,'algo',500000,2,1);
    insert into productos (id_pro, nom_pro, pre_pro, id_usu, id_est) values (2,'otra cosa',8000,3,1);
    insert into productos (id_pro, nom_pro, pre_pro, id_usu, id_est) values (3,'algo mas',135000,3,1);
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre].

Comment: El código siempre en la pregunta, por favor. Si por encima de que pides ayuda me haces pinchar en un enlace extraño, casi que prefiero no arriesgarme a ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Konvex, esto es mala práctica, pero para efectos de resolución podrías intentar lo siguiente : `DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE pil_usu='CHORICILLO' cascade;`

Comment: Veo que tienes una tabla de estados, así que, ¿Por qué en lugar de eliminar usuarios no simplemente los inhabilitas? Conservarías la integridad referencial y no te haces líos con los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque en la tabla `Productos` tienes una referencia al código de usuario y la base de datos intenta mantener la integridad referencial. Por eso al intentar borrar el usuario te dice que no puedes.

Si quieres eliminar un usuario, deberías eliminar antes todos los productos que hacen referencia a ese usuario o modificar el código de usuario de la tabla de `Productos` para que haga referencia a otro código de usuario válido.

Es decir, deberías hacer algo así (adapta las consultas a tu base de datos, escribo leyendo tus especificaciones):

```sql
DELETE FROM productos WHERE id_usu IN (SELECT id_usu FROM usuarios WHERE  pil_usu='CHORICILLO');
delete from usuarios where pil_usu='CHORICILLO';
```

De todas formas, yo intentaría quitar esa referencia al usuario, no tiene mucho sentido que cuando borres un usuario de la base de datos, tengas la necesidad de borrar también todos sus productos asociados